# How to use C++ comments "//" in c-mode?

Tags: c, cc-mode

In c-mode comment-region is adding `/* */` style comments.

Is there a way to default to using C++ style `//` prefix in C source files instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for toggling between block-style and line-style comments was added a few months ago, and should be included in the next release.

If you have a snapshot of the development version of emacs (from `master` after June 15, 2017), you can use `(c-toggle-comment-style)` to toggle the comment style.

See http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=7a2038d7c887e4fa08a91950a7494d1dd20c39e1

And the related conversation on emacs-devel: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=7a2038d7c887e4fa08a91950a7494d1dd20c39e1

**EDIT:**

To enable them by default:

`(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda () (c-toggle-comment-style -1)))`

Comment: Is there a way to set the default? - so toggling each time isn't needed.

Comment: You still need a hook I think. See updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done by changing `comment-start` & `comment-end`.

```elisp
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda () (setq comment-start "//"
                                        comment-end   "")))
```

---

Found the answer after further searching [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6913955/432509)

Comment: You may also be interested in `comment-start-skip` for certain use cases within `c-mode`.